# Как передать данные функции в другую функию С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, разработка-игр, void

как передать все данные объектов из функции setup в функцию graphic, чтоб небыло ошибки что объект let1 и его данные не были найдены

````
class let
{
public:
    int let_x, let_y;
};

void setup()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    let let1;
    let1.let_x = rand() % 40 + 15;
    let1.let_y = rand() % 9;
    if (let1.let_x > 40)
    {
        let1.let_x -= 20;
    }
    let let2;
    let2.let_x = rand() % 40 + 15;
    let2.let_y = rand() % 9;
    if (let2.let_x > 40)
    {
        let2.let_x -= 20;
    }
    let let3;
    let3.let_x = rand() % 40 + 15;
    let3.let_y = rand() % 9;
    if (let3.let_x > 40)
    {
        let3.let_x -= 20;
    }
    let let4;
    let4.let_x = rand() % 40 + 15;
    let4.let_y = rand() % 9;
    if (let4.let_x > 40)
    {
        let4.let_x -= 20;
    }
    let let5;
    let5.let_x = 0;
    let5.let_y = 0;
    
    system("color F4");
    dir = STOP;
    //game_condition = true;
    hero_x = 0, hero_y = 5;
    //let_x = 0, let_y = 0;
}

void graphiс()
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < max_y; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < max_x; j++)
        {
            if (i == hero_y && j == hero_x)
            {
                cout << "|";
            }
            if (i == let1.let_y && j == let1.let_x)
            {
                cout << "#";
                ++let1;
            }
            cout << " ";
        }
        if (i > max_y)
        {
            break;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    system("cls");
} ```
````

Comment: Вынести их вначале из `setup` — куда, дело ваше. Вам виднее, что это. А дальше все просто — `void graphiс(let& let1)`

Answer (score 1):

Немного странный у вас код. Но, если отвечать на поставленный вопрос, то:

```
void setup(){
//operation
graphic(let1);//передаем в ф-цию,условно let1
}
```

А в функции **graphic()**:

```
void graphic(let& data){
//operation
}
```